# Pandas: replace values in column if they apprear in another column - with values from a third one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a somewhat complicated action I need to perform. I have a dataframe: lets call it df1, with column "a". some of its values appear in df2 - another dataframe, in a column called "b". if a certain value is in "b" in df2, I would like to replace them with a values from df3, column "c", in a row number same as the row number in "b" that matched the value in "a". if the value in not in "b", I would like to replace it with a contant "constant". any value can appear more then once in each column.

so if

```
a = [r,t,y,u,i,t]
b = [q,u,n,r,z,d,e,r,t,r]
c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,9,4]
constant = 200
```

a becomes:

```
a = [4,9,200,2,200,9]
```

How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dictionary by `b` and `c`, only necessary same lengths and unique values of `b` and then `map` values of `a` by `get` for possible specify default value:

```
d = dict(zip(b, c))

out = [d.get(x, constant) for x in a]
print (out)
[4, 9, 200, 2, 200, 9]
```

With DataFrames:

```
d = dict(zip(df2.b, df3.c))

out = [d.get(x, constant) for x in df1.a]
print (out)
[4, 9, 200, 2, 200, 9]
```

Or use `map` with replace missing non matched values by `fillna`:

```
out = df1.a.map(d).fillna(constant)
```